# Для чего нужны и как записываются вложенные блоки try?

Tags: java

Для чего нужны и как записываются вложенные блоки try?

Comment: @Niki, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Это исключения, используются для отслеживания ошибок в коде. Элементарный пример:

```
try {
    TextView mTextView;
    mTextView.setText("text") //TextView не инициализирован и будет NullPointerException

}
catch (NullPointerException e) {//Если в коде блока try будет NullPointerException         //приложение не упадет, а выполнит код из блока catch

   e.printStackTrace()
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, e.toString());

}
finally {

// код, который нужно выполнить после завершения блока try
}
```